# Parts of Speech in the sentence

Tags: parts-of-speech

[**Source**](http://brainly.com/question/1836132)

"Designing vulgar structures is typical of that architect."

Where are the following parts of speech are located: Subject, AVP/LVP, DO, IO, Subject Complement

Edit:
*Designing* and *is* are both verbs. *Designing* - Action Verb; *Is* - Linking Verb. I know that if there are two verbs, you go with the second verb. So, 
 "Designing vulgar structures **is** (LVP) typical of that architect."

The subject confuses me because both *structures* and *architect* are nouns. In my opinion, since *is* is the LVP, the subject could be *architect*. So, 
 "Designing vulgar structures **is** (LVP) typical of that **architect** (S)."

What I don't know is where the DO and IO are located. This sentence does not have a prepositional phrase, so it could (probably does) include both DO & IO.

Sorry if there is some confusion, English is not my native language.

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Please use the [edit] link to tell us where _you_ think those parts of speech are in your sentence. If we know what exactly what you don't understand, we can help you. Please review our [**tour**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [**Help Center**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages for advice on writing a good question.

Comment: "Designing" is a _gerund_ here; that might be a useful hint. Was it you who asked this question at Brainly.com, or are you answering it? Either way, you should always add a link to the source (when possible) if quoting text in a question.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I was the one who asked the question at Brainly.com .... Didn't help me much for nobody answered. What about the things that I think are the part of the sentence? Are they correct or not?

Comment: What kind of phrase is _of that architect_?

Comment: Prepositional phrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Designing vulgar structures is typical of that architect."

- "Designing" is a subject (gerund)
- "vulgar structures" (direct object, NP)
- "is" (linking verb or predicator)
- "typical of that architect" (subject complement where *typical* is an adjective and *of that architect* is an indirect object or a prepositional NP.)